# Can vs could_ possibility

Tags: grammar

As I learned, "can" refers to present ability, and "could" refers to present possibility.

"could" also refers to past ability. But in this post, I only want to refer to ability and possibility in the present.

I have some examples:

> (1) Do you think he **can/could** win the race tomorrow?
>
> (2) Spending a lot of time using computer **can/could** lead to eye
> disorders.

I actually don't know the difference between "can" and "could' in these sentences. Could you please tell me?

Does that "can" show a stronger possibility than "could" in these sentences?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it does.

*He can win the race* = he is fit enough to be able to do so.

*It can lead to eye disorders* = it sometimes does.

In both cases, *could* implies a hypothetical outcome; something that might possibly happen.

Comment: I talk to a friend: Spending a lot of time using computer CAN / COULD lead to eye disorders. You shouldn’t pay a lot of time on your computer. Which one should I use.?

Comment: That depends on whether you know for certain that there have been cases of people getting eye disorders from too much computer use, or whether you have just read somewhere that it might happen. (This isn't a hard and fast rule, just my interpretation of the difference.) NB It's _using computers_ or _using a computer_.

Comment: Similarly, “It CAN/ COULD be expensive to keep a cat. You should think carefully if you want to have one.” if you are sure that having a cat is expensive, use “can”. If you are not sure about this, use “could”. Right?

Comment: _It can be expensive_ - some people find it expensive (for example, if the cat needs a lot of visits to the vet). _It could be expensive_ - you foresee that it may be.